# http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ is not working

Tags: react-native

debugger status is loading and below image show's error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install in roject path> npm install react-native-debugger --save
0. paste http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ on chrome browser
1. in cmd run > react-native run-android

2. in emulator, after show app, press on keyboard ctrl+M to show menu -> select Dev setting -> then change  **Debug server host &... to "localhost:8081"**

3.in emulator, after show app, press on keyboard ctrl+M to show menu -> select Dev setting -> then **enable Hot loading**

4. press f12 then go to console change chrome console setting, one dropdown to **debuggerworke.js** and then other dropdown **select verbose**

5.notice to port that emulator is running, in node window it is shown in box at top. if it was not 8081, you must change it in case 4 above.
I hope it can work...

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can replace with your **IPAddress** with **localhost**.

http://IPADDRESS:8081/debugger-ui/